# About the dynamic memory allocation for arrays in C language

Tags: c, algorithm, memory, merge

What I want to achieve is to create a merged array of two sorted arrays, such as [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] + [2, 4, 6, 8, 10] => [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 8, 10], by comparing the two elements in each array

And I am trying to apply such algorithm to dynamically allocated arrays and throwing pointer arguments to custom-made merge() function. Please refer to the following excerpt

```
int* merge(int*, int*);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    int* arrayA;
    int* arrayB;
    int* mergedArray;
    
    int index;
    
    arrayA = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
    arrayB = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
    
    //filling out the array A with number elements like [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    for(index = 0; index < 5; index++){
        *(arrayA + sizeof(int) * index) = index;
        printf("%d", *(arrayA + sizeof(int) * index));
    }
    
    //filling out the array A with number elements like [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
    for(index = 0; index < 5; index++){
        *(arrayB + sizeof(int) * index) = (index + 1) * 2;
        printf("%d", *(arrayB + sizeof(int) * index));
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    
    mergedArray = (int *) merge(arrayA, arrayB);
    
    for(index = 0; index < 10; index++){
        printf("%d", *(mergedArray + sizeof(int) * index));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The merge functions is as follows

```
//My take on merge() function

int *merge(int *arrayA, int *arrayB) {
  int *mergedArray;
  int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; // i for arrayA / j for arrayB / k for mergedArray
  int arrayALength;
  int arrayBLength;

  mergedArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
  arrayALength = 5;
  arrayBLength = 5;

  while (i < arrayALength && j < arrayBLength) {
    printf("%d / %d\n", *(arrayA + (i) * sizeof(int)), *(arrayB + (j) * sizeof(int)));

    if (*(arrayA + (sizeof(int) * i)) < *(arrayB + (sizeof(int) * j))) {
      *(mergedArray + (k++ * sizeof(int))) = *(arrayA + (i++ * sizeof(int)));
      printf("%d", *(mergedArray + (k - 1) * sizeof(int)));
    } else {
      *(mergedArray + (k++ * sizeof(int))) = *(arrayB + (j++ * sizeof(int)));
      printf("%d", *(mergedArray + (k - 1) * sizeof(int)));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  for (; i < arrayALength; i++) {
    *(mergedArray + (k++ * sizeof(int))) = *(arrayA + (i * sizeof(int)));
  }
  for (; j < arrayBLength; j++) {
    *(mergedArray + (k++ * sizeof(int))) = *(arrayB + (j * sizeof(int)));
  }
  return mergedArray;
}
```

The result is...

```
01234
246810
0 / 2
0
1 / 2
1
2 / 2
2
2 / 4
2
4 / 4
4
4 / 0
0
4 / 1
1
4 / 2
2
0122401240Program ended with exit code: 0
```

If you take a look at the first line "01234" in the result, I am pretty confident that [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] is stored inside the memory where arrayA is pointing at, yet inside the merge() function if I print the corresponding element, it shows [0, 1, 2, 4], leaving out the element '3' in the middle.

Not only that the program's final result "0122401240" does show that there is logic fallacy in my code, which I could not find.

If you could see the logical error, please do not hesitate to point out one, and could you tell me why there was difference in elements in allocated memory?

Comment: Why do do you write confusing code like `*(arrayA + sizeof(int) * index)` rather than the much clearer `arrayA[index]`? And it looks wrong anyway as it is doing pointer arithmetic and would need to be `*(arrayA + index)`

Comment: Haven't looked through all your code, but `*(arrayA + sizeof(int) * index) = index;` isn't right. Pointer arithmetic in C takes the size of the pointed objects into consideration, so `*(arrayA + index) = index;` would be better. (Or just `arrayA[index] = index;`)

Comment: Yes! I wanted to use arrayA[index] instead of a rather tedious arithmetics done in my code, but it always returned a rather odd result, so I thought, I would stick to my original take. Now I know that "C takes the size of the pointed objects into consideration," maybe I should first start by removing all the sizeof() functions.

Comment: @kaylum Those two are not equivalent.  `*(arrayA + sizeof(int) * index)` is equivalent to `arrayA[sizeof(int) * index]`, not `arrayA[index]`.  It's probably a bug that it's multiplying by `sizeof(int)`.  Remember, pointer addition implicitly scales, and `*(a+b)` is equivalent to `a[b]`.  Both version scale the integer by the size of the pointer target.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, that's why I said it looks wrong and should be `*(arrayA + index)`. Probably I could have worded the comment a bit better.

Comment: Thank you! I have sorted out my problem, and yes, the pointer addition indeed was implicitly scales. I appreciate your helps!

Comment: @kaylum Oh right, I guess I misread your comment.  But yeah, the explicit redundant scaling seems to have been the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really complex, you could simplify it a lot

A way to solve your issue is to make these two arrays contiguous so that you can handle it like a single array as shown in the code below

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int mysort(const void* a, const void* b){
    return (*(int*)a-*(int*)b);
}


int main(){
    int sz1= 5, sz2=5;
    int* arr1 = malloc((sz1+sz2)*sizeof(int)); // Allocate for both arrays
    int* arr2 = &arr1[sz1]; // Go to the 2nd array

    my_fill(arr1); // Setup your arrays as you wish
    my_fill(arr2);

    qsort(arr1, sz1+sz2, sizeof(int), mysort); // Sort both arrays using the standard qsort.

}
```

Obviously, if you want to use a custom sorting algorithm such as merge sort, this is possible. You can replace `qsort` with your custom algorithm.

Comment: This is pretty cool! This is a way easier method to allocate a memory space! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should benefit from the fact that the input arrays are already sorted. Simply take the smallest value and copy it to the output array. For each input array maintain an index that tells you where the next unused element is.

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* mergeSortedArraysToSingleSortedArray(int* arrA, size_t szA, int* arrB, size_t szB)
{
    int* res = malloc((szA + szB) * sizeof *arrA);
    if (res == NULL) return NULL;
    
    size_t iA = 0;
    size_t iB = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    
    // Merge from A and B
    while (iA < szA && iB < szB)
    {
        if (arrA[iA] <= arrB[iB])
        {
            res[i] = arrA[iA];
            ++iA;
        }
        else
        {
            res[i] = arrB[iB];
            ++iB;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    
    // Take rest of A (if any)
    while (iA < szA)
    {
        res[i] = arrA[iA];
        ++iA;
        ++i;
    }

    // Take rest of B (if any)
    while (iB < szB)
    {
        res[i] = arrB[iB];
        ++iB;
        ++i;
    }
    
    return res;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int arrA[] =  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int arrB[] =  {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
    size_t szA = sizeof(arrA)/sizeof(*arrA);
    size_t szB = sizeof(arrB)/sizeof(*arrB);
    
    int* arrMerged = mergeSortedArraysToSingleSortedArray(arrA, szA, arrB, szB);
    if (arrMerged)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < szA + szB; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d ", arrMerged[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 2 3 4 4 6 8 10
```